# How to parse a json response in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

First time working with JSON in Rails and trying to figure out something which seems like it should be quite basic.  I'm working w/ the Stripe Rails Library and trying to parse out and set one of the JSON elements to a variable.

Here is my actual attempt:

```
    coupon = Stripe::Coupon.retrieve(self.discount_code)
    parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(coupon)
    discount_amount = parsed_json["percent_off"]
```

This line works:

```
coupon = Stripe::Coupon.retrieve("save50percent")
```

Running "puts coupon" in the console shows the JSON string

JSON:  {"id":"test50","duration":"once","duration_in_months":null,"livemode":false,"max_redemptions":null,"object":"coupon","percent_off":50,"redeem_by":null,"times_redeemed":0}

but trying to run:

```
parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(coupon)
```

results in the following error:

```
TypeError: can't convert Stripe::Coupon into String
```

I haven't even gotten to trying to parse out the value from the JSON - which i'm sure i've approached incorrectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message says it all: `coupon` is a `Stripe::Coupon`, not a `String`. Try using the available [`to_json` method](http://rubydoc.info/github/stripe/stripe-ruby/master/Stripe/StripeObject#to_json-instance_method)

Comment: That did it!  I didn't realize it wasn't coming back as a JSON - but it seems obvious now of course ;)

Answer (score -1):

I would assume the coupon is not a string that looks like JSON, but looks like one when you print it. Try decoding it's string representation rather. I'm not sure of the code for this(I'm not a RoR programmer) but I've seen many similar situations to the one you're in...

Comment: It's a string, but not a JSON string; they don't start with "JSON: ".

Comment: Your answer also didn't seem terribly helpful. If you're really worried about it, I could un-downvote (but I'll need you to edit your answer; my vote is locked)